# Installing a bathroom vent duct through a concrete roof

Tags: roof, ducts, exhaust-fan

I recently bought a two-story condo unit. I decided to replace the bathroom exhaust fans upstairs, but when I removed the old fans, I discovered the exhaust duct was not connected to the roof vent: both ducts traveled all the way to the vent and joined at a tee, but there was a six-inch gap between tee and roof vent. Like this:

[image: exhaust duct meets concrete ceiling]

As you can see, it's a flat concrete roof (I think it's hollow-core slab), and the duct is 4" galvanized. An opening was cut into the concrete for the duct and vent. The duct tape on the tee makes me think it was attached to something before, but when I get my phone in to look straight up, I see this:

[image: vent seen from below]

The roof vent is flush with the concrete, but off-center, so it is obstructed (only by about half an inch) on one side. It's unclear how the tee ever could have connected, and there's no sign of any missing pieces.

The question is: How do I attach a new exhaust duct to this vent?

I am accessing the space from a 7" by 7" hole in the bathroom wall, which is tiled:

[image: shower and fan location]

All I can see from the hole is what you see in the first picture; the vent can't be seen directly.

I could use tools to chip away the concrete, but I'd need a tool that can be used one-handed in a confined space without any visibility. (I tried a drill with a masonry bit in the hopes of knocking some chunks off, but it's simply too big and I can't see what I'm doing.) I've thought of using flexible duct taped from the *inside*, which could work around the obstruction, but would the tape eventually fail from the heat and humidity? I could make a better access hole, perhaps directly underneath, but then I'd have to retile my bathroom ceiling.

Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve roofing work, since then the condo association has to get involved to approve roof work, making it harder to get contractors interested in the job.

Comment: I can not help you here, my bathroom vents go horizontally to the side walls, not to the roof. However, I would caution you chipping off the roof concrete

Comment: Is the existing tee opening the same size as the duct going up to the roof?

Comment: The exterior vent is 4" and the tee is 4". There are reducers on the ducts, since the old exhaust fans had 3" exhausts. I plan to replace the ductwork with 4", since my new fans are 4".

Comment: Would you be able to drop a 3.5" duct inside the 4" duct from the roof into the tee?

Comment: Possibly. It would likely fit, but would it need to be sealed somehow?

Comment: Also, I should clarify that I can remove the tee pretty easily and replace it with something else. So I could put in a 3.5" duct from below as well, or anything else that I could fit through the hole in the wall

Comment: I'd suggest getting comfortable with either retiling your ceiling, or (better, since this won't be the only time, probably) installing a nice **large** access panel in your tiled ceiling if you want to do this right and avoid roof work. Swap your 7x7 for an 18x18 (or more) and you can get a lot more done, a lot more reasonably.

Comment: I added a photo showing the location of the fan. Retiling is possible, but an access panel would have to be in the middle of the shower ceiling, which doesn't seem great

Comment: Something's missing: where's the other half of the torn tape on the joint a the top of the tee?

Comment: @Jasen I wondered the same thing, but when I disassembled and removed the tee, there was nothing that would obviously fit there. Possibly there used to be an extra piece but it was removed at some point. This makes me wonder if it was previously connected, and somehow the vent shifted while someone was working in the space

Answer (score 1):

I'd get some duct that is 1/2" diameter smaller than the duct going through the concrete. Run the smaller duct inside the larger one up to the roof then connect the bottom of the new duct to the tee with some mastic and foil tape and squirt some expanding foam between the old and new ducts.

Answer (score 0):

Only proper way now is to make an access above the shower, so you can get at the whole lot from inside the shower cubicle. Yes, it'll involve cutting some tiles, but for the future, it'll be easier to access for any problems. Then you'll be able to open up the concrete at its lower level, and be able, using both access shafts, to put it all together far better than the cobbled up arrangement we see. Something like a small loft hatch, tiled the same as the top of the cubicle would look good.

Or, hire a small camera on a flexi, and chip away like a surgeon doing a keyhole operation.